# Mapping an Either list to integers

Tags: haskell, lambda, either

I am trying to do the following:

```
processRights :: [Either a Int] -> Int
processRights xs = map (\Right x -> x, \Left x -> 0) xs
```

So, `xs` is a `[Either a Int]`, and I wish to produce a mapped list of the same length where for each int there is the same int, 0 otherwise.

How can I acomplish that?

Comment: You might consider using library functions `map` and  [either](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a-%3Ec)%20-%3E%20(b-%3Ec)%20-%3E%20Either%20a%20b%20-%3E%20c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `either`, `id` and `const` functions:

```
processRights :: [Either a Int] -> [Int]
processRights = map $ either (const 0) id
```

`either` runs the first function for any `Left`, the second function for any `Right`.

`id` returns its argument.

`const` ignores its second argument and returns its first argument, its intended use is that e.g. `const 0` becomes a function that ignores its argument and just returns 0.

Comment: That done it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Slightly simpler, `map (fromRight 0)`.

Comment: Simpler still, `map sum`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's terrible. I love it.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed code is really, really close, actually! Here's a working version with minimal changes:

```
processRights xs = map (\case Right x -> x; Left x -> 0) xs
```

You will need to turn on the `LambdaCase` language extension. (And of course, as mentioned in other answers, there are more idiomatic ways to achieve this effect.)

Answer (score 1):

A clear way to do this is to work with a helper function. Indeed:

```
processRights :: [Either a Int] -> [Int]
processRights = map go
    where go (Right x) = x
             (Left _) = 0
```

This is not the most concise way, but it shows what is happening. You can simplify this with [**`fromRight :: b -> Either a b -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:fromRight) where we provide a value to use or a `Left x` element, and it will thus either select that value, or the value wrapped in the `Right` data constructor, so:

```
import Data.Either(fromRight)

processRights :: Num b => [Either a b] -> [b]
processRights = map (fromRight 0)
```

Comment: `[Int]` instead of `Int` at the end of the first line.